# Rails not letting after_create execute without user_id param. Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, model, controller

In my `Game` model, I have

```
class Game < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :assignments
    has_many :users, through: :assignments

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :assignments

    after_create :create_assignments

    def create_assignments
        3.times { Assignment.create!(game_id: id, user_id: 1) }
    end
end
```

This works but I need the `user_id` to be blank when it's created (it will be edited at a later time). It won't create assignments unless there is a `user_id` with a value.

I've tried leaving it blank and omitting it, but that doesn't work. I think I need to put `optional: true` somewhere but I'm pretty stumped on this one.

Comment: Just add `optional: true`, to belongs_to :assignment, in `user` model

Comment: I knew it had to go somewhere! It actually goes on `beloings_to: user` not `game`. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Needed to add `:optional => true` on Assignment Model

```
class Assignment < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :game
    belongs_to :user, :optional => true
end
```